# Как отслеживать изменения в LocalStorage | Angular 7

Tags: angular, localstorage

Как отслеживать изменения в LocalStorage в Angular 7. Есть установленный angular-2-local-storage. Возможно в нем есть какие-то сервисы? Я туда кладу объект и мне нужно мониторить не изменился ли он.

Answer (score 0):

Что то вроде этого...

```
import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LocalStorageModule.forRoot({
            prefix: 'my-app',
            storageType: 'localStorage',
            notifyOptions: {
               setItem: true,
            },
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        ..
    ],
    providers: [
        ..
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }




import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
    // ...
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor (
        private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        this._localStorageService.setItems$.subscribe(e => {
           console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```